# Show only first row in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want only the first row to show up in this query. However, because each user has a distinct service, the users show up more than once. I only want to show the first row then the other rows in a separate query `ORDERING BY 'id'`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (7)
    id,
    fname,
    lname,
    dob,
    services
FROM 
    T1
ORDER BY 
    id
```

Output:

```
id  fname   lname   dob         services    
------------------------------------------
100 Joe     Blue    2/20/2001   JDT 
100 Joe     Blue    2/20/2001   VOCP    
101 Mark    Pink    1/5/2000    OPAP    
101 Mark    Pink    1/5/2000    AARCHD  
102 Wally   Green   1/2/2000    AARCHD  
102 Wally   Green   1/2/2000    OPAP    
103 Steve   Yellow  1/10/2000   AARCHD
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server. And you need to provide some kind of detail here. Is the data you posted sample data, desired output or what you get from your query?

Comment: So don't include the `services`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` in the `order by`.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first row" unless another column specifies the ordering.

In this case, I'm using `service`, but I'm not sure if that is what you intend:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES t1.*
FROM T1
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY service);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show distinct users:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    fname,
    lname,
    dob
FROM 
    T1
ORDER BY 
    id
```